# Load data in a Global Temporary Table

Tags: sql, oracle, temp-tables

I have two different Oracle sessions ("session A" and "session B") on the same Oracle user.

A Global Temporary Table is populated, in "session A", with about 320,000 records.

How can I quickly insert the same 320,000 records in the global temporary table of the "session B"?

Thank you in advance for your kind suggestions!

**EDIT: I have forgotten to specify that I am allowed to create ONLY GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLES.**

**EDIT: I have forgotten to specify that I am not allowed to create database links**

Comment: You could instead create a table that is accessible to both sessions...  More information would help - what version of Oracle, and why do you need a temp table?

Comment: I am only allowed to create global temporary tables...

Comment: The Oracle version I am using is: Oracle Database 10G Release 2

Comment: Any reason you're not allowed to use a "regular" table ?

Comment: Is a production database!  The DBA Administrators don't allow me to create phisical tables.  Is it sufficient as reason?

Comment: If you have a legitimate need to create a temporary table in a production database (which as far as Oracle is concerned is a permanent table with transient data) and to run a process against that production database, that is almost certainly sufficient justification to create a permanent table.  DBAs will generally ask for justification to create new tables and may want to put your table in a separate schema and/or tablespace, but the restriction that you not use a permanent table does not make sense if that is the most efficient way to proceed and you are allowed to create a temp table.

Comment: Justin, I agree 100%, but my DBAs don't permit in any way the creation of phisical tables.  No workaround to obtain this grant!

Comment: I can't think of any reason why a DBA who disallows the creation of a table, allows the creation of GTT. Very strange.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DBMS_PIPE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_pipe.htm#CHDDFCFC) is the 'classic' mechanism for pushing information from one session to another. Session A would have to push data into the pipe and session B would have to pull it.

But generally the idea of databases is that sessions are independent and any commonality is in the preserved data. Going against this suggests you are using the wrong tool.

Comment: OK, could you make an example on how to transfer a record from "Session A" to "Session B", using PUSH and PULL?  Please assume that the source table in "Session A" and the target table in "Session B" are identical tables.

Answer (score 5):

The data within a temporary table is only ever visible to the current session, so I don't think there's a way to do what you want to do without another approach.

Answer (score 2):

The data in a global temporary table is only visible to the session that inserted it.  So you would have to run the same process that populated the table in session B.

Of course, the fact that you appear to want to access the same 320,000 rows in two different sessions would seem to imply that a global temporary table is not the appropriate data structure to be using.  Perhaps you want to load that data into a permanent table (possibly along with some sort of identifier if you will have multiple SessionA/ SessionB pairs).  Or perhaps whatever logic Session B is running ought to be run by Session A.

And just taking a step back, since Oracle implements multi-version read consistency such that readers don't block writers and writers don't block readers, it would be very unusual to need to have a 320,000 row temporary table in the first place.

Comment: OK, but with the assumption that I am not allowed to create phisical tables (but only global temporary tables), and that I am not allowed to create DBLINKs, what is in your opinion the fastest way to replicate the 320,000 rows in the "session B"?

Comment: Where is Session A getting the 320,000 rows to insert into the temporary table?  And where are database links coming in to play?  Are Session A and Session B on two different databases as well?

Comment: The 320,000 rows come from a long query.  This result has to be joined with a similar result in another session with another global temporary table.  I run the same procedure in two session, to parallelize the executions and to low the execution time.

Comment: Any mechanism we come up with to move data from a global temporary table in one session to a global temporary table in another session would almost certainly require more time to move the data than you are saving by manually parallelizing the query.  So in the end, you're almost certainly better off not splitting the query up and just materializing the 640,000 rows in Session A's table.